# How to fetch the nth highest salary from a table without using TOP and sub-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Recently in an interview I was asked to write a query where I had to fetch nth highest salary from a table without using TOP and any sub-query ?

I got totally confused as the only way I knew to implement it uses both TOP and sub-query.

Kindly provide its solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are three salaries: 10, 20 and 20, which is the second highest? Is it 20 because the top two are both 20? Or is it 10 because 20 is the highest and 10 is the next highest? In other words, do you want to fetch the nth highest *distinct* salary or the nth highest salary?

Comment: Interesting that the interviewer said "subquery". I'd have said it's a "derived table" for the TOP DESC/TOP ASC solution

Comment: @Mark the desired output is distinct nth highest salary.

Comment: Then take a look at DENSE_RANK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try a CTE - Common Table Expression:

```
WITH Salaries AS
(
    SELECT 
       SalaryAmount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalaryAmount DESC) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM 
       dbo.SalaryTable
)
SELECT
  SalaryAmount
FROM
  Salaries
WHERE
   RowNum <= 5
```

This gets the top 5 salaries in descending order - you can play with the `RowNumn` value and basically retrieve any slice from the list of salaries.

There are [other ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) available in SQL Server that can be used, too - e.g. there's `NTILE` which will split your results into n groups of equal size (as closely as possible), so you could e.g. create 10 groups like this:

```
WITH Salaries AS
(
    SELECT 
       SalaryAmount, NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY SalaryAmount DESC) AS 'NTile'
    FROM 
       dbo.SalaryTable
)
SELECT
  SalaryAmount
FROM
  Salaries
WHERE
   NTile = 1
```

This will split your salaries into 10 groups of equal size - and the one with `NTile=1` is the "TOP 10%" group of salaries.

Comment: Sir....In first Solution why we are not using the Partition by clause in cte function..??

Comment: @AkhileshSingh: because there's no requirement to show the "top n for each (something)" . The OP just wants the n-th highest salary over **all** salaries - not n-th hightest in a particular group (n-th highest for each country, for each profession or something like that).

Comment: I got it...Thank uu :)

Answer (score 11):

```
;with cte as(
Select salary,
row_number() over (order by salary desc) as rn
from salaries
)

select salary 
from cte 
where rn=@n
```

(or use `dense_rank` in place of `row_number` if you want the nth highest distinct salary amount)

Answer (score 5):

```
Select  * 
From    Employee E1 
Where
N = (Select Count(Distinct(E2.Salary)) From Employee E2 Where E2.Salary >= E1.Salary)
```

Comment: +1 because this does work but ranking functions are much more efficient. Also it clearly uses a sub query but I'm not sure if the question meant without using `TOP` **or** a sub query.

Comment: Because of `DISTINCT` this is rather an equivalent of `DENSE_RANK()` than `ROW_NUMBER()`. (And the question isn't absolutely clear which one is more suitable, so it might be fine too.)

Comment: @Venktesh I was looking for this, pls explain how the where clause sub query works.

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as(
select VendorId,IncomeDay,IncomeAmount,
Row_Number() over ( order by IncomeAmount desc) as RowNumber
 from DailyIncome 
 )

 select * from cte
 where RowNumber=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Display 5th Min Sal Emp Table.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Dense_Rank () Over (ORDER BY Sal ASC) AS Rnk, Emp.* FROM Emp) WHERE
Rnk=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT Salary,
    rownum AS roworder
  FROM (select distinct Salary from employer)
  ORDER BY Salary
  )
 where roworder = 6
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can simply be done as following for second highest-

```
Select MAX(Salary) from employer where Salary NOT IN(Select MAX(Salary) from employer);
```

But for Nth highest we have to use CTE(Common Table Expression).

Answer (score 1):

If there are duplicate entries of

30,000,
23,000,
 
23,000,
15,000,
14,800

then above selected query will not return correct output.

find correct query as below:

```
with salaries as
(
    select Salary,DENSE_RANK() over (order by salary desc) as 'Dense' 
    from Table_1
)
select distinct salary from salaries
where dense=3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. It may very easy to find nth rank items by using CTE
**

```
with result AS
( 
 SELECT  *,dense_rank() over( order by Salary) as ranks FROM Employee
) 
select *from RESULT Where ranks = 2
```

**

Answer (score 1):

To find the Nth highest salary :
Table name - Emp

```
        emplyee_id     salary
             1          2000
             2          3000
             3          5000
             4          8000
             5          7000
             6          2000
             7          1000
```

sql query -> here N is higest salary to be found :

```
select salary from (select salary from Emp order by salary DESC LIMIT N) AS E order by ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT salery,name
 FROM employ
 ORDER BY salery DESC limit 1, OFFSET n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE_name (salary,name)
AS
( row_num() over (order by desc salary) as num from tablename )
select salary, name from CTE_name where num =1;
```

This will work in oracle

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the Nth highest salary, we are only considering unique salaries.Highest salary means no salary is higher than it, Second highest means only one salary is higher than it, 3rd highest means two salaries are higher than it,similarly,Nth highest salary means N-1 salaries are higher than it.
Well, you can do by using **LIMIT** keyword, which provides pagination 
capability.You can do like below:

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT N-1, 1
```

Ex: 2nd highest salary in MySQL without subquery:

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: This isn't valid in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

6- ways to write Second Highest salary..**

1.select * from employee order by Salary desc offset 1 rows fetch next 1 row only

2.select max(salary) from Employee where salary<(select max(salary) from Employee)

3.select MAX(Salary) from Employee WHERE Salary NOT IN (select MAX(Salary) from Employee );

4.select max(e1.salary) from Employee e1,Employee e2 where e1.salary

5.with cte as(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by SALARY  desc) AS ROWNUM FROM EMPLOYEE as rn) 
select *From cte where ROWNUM=2

6.select max(e1.Salary) from Employee e1,Employee e2 where e1.Salary

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to get nth Highest salary using NTILE function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SAL INTO #TEMP_A FROM EMPLOYEE 

DECLARE @CNT INT

SELECT @CNT=COUNT(1) FROM #TEMP_A

;WITH RES
AS(
SELECT SAL,NTILE(@CNT) OVER (ORDER BY SAL DESC) NTL
FROM #TEMP_A )

SELECT SALFROM RES WHERE NTL=3

DROP TABLE #TEMP_A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
salary ---> table name

SELECT salary
FROM salary S1
WHERE 5-1 = (
      SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ( S2.salary ) )
      FROM salary S2 
      WHERE S2.salary >  S1.salary );
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Highest sal using ms sql server:

`select sal from emp where sal=(select max(sal) from emp)`

Second highest sal:

`select max(sal) from emp where sal not in (select max(sal) from emp)`

Comment: the question says without using a sub query

Answer (score -2):

What if we are required to find Nth highest salary without Row_Number,Rank, Dense Rank and Sub Query?

Hope this below Query Helps out.

select * from [dbo].[Test] order by salary desc

```
Emp_Id  Name    Salary  Department
 4      Neelu   10000   NULL
 2      Rohit   4000    HR
 3      Amit    3000    OPS
 1      Rahul   2000    IT



select B.Salary from TEst B join Test A
on B.Salary<=A.Salary 
group by (B.Salary)
having count(B.salary)=2
```

Result:- 4000, The 2nd Highest.