# SQL Query to find Nth highest salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How to find Nth Highest Salary without using any subquery in MS SQL?

Comment: The question is vague. Post your tables schema.

Comment: What if two people have the same salary around the N'th point? For example: what should the fourth item in this ordered list be? 10 9 8 8 8 7 7 7 6 5

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet true but the question you link to doesn't specify the version of SQL Server (except in a comment) so the answers don't use the potentially more efficient/clearer windowing functions available since SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Another closer duplicate candidate: ["How to fetch the nth highest salary from a table without using TOP and sub-query"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3645528/515908).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH cte1
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS RN, * FROM Salaries
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte1
WHERE RN = 5 <-- Nth highest
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` may not be what is wanted here. `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` may be more appropriate depending on the requirements.

Comment: DENSE_RANK(), in my case gives 2 rows. then should i distinct in that case?

Comment: @Xor it depends on your requirements, what results do you want to see if two people have the same salary around the N'th point?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the row_number function. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx